# Collapsable list optimisation in pure js

Tags: javascript, dom

I am building a collapsable list and in my attempt to optimize my code, I find myself making something that spits errors, but for a reason still works somehow.

old code: http://jsfiddle.net/3pmcrqmj/

```
function addEvent(element, myEvent, fnc) {
return ((element.attachEvent) ? element.attachEvent('on' + myEvent, fnc) : element.addEventListener(myEvent, fnc, false));
}

var list = document.getElementById('list');
var items = list.getElementsByTagName('ul');
var items2 = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i = 0; len = items.length, i < len ; i++){

    items[i].parentNode.setAttribute('class','collapse');

    addEvent(items[i].parentNode, 'click', function(event) {

        event = event || window.event;

        event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble=true);

        if(this.getAttribute('class')==='collapse'){
            this.setAttribute('class','expand');
        } else {
            this.removeAttribute('class');
            var temp = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
                temp.setAttribute('class','collapse');
            },200);
        }

    });
}
```

My fixing attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/3pmcrqmj/1/

```
function addEvent(element, myEvent, fnc) {
return ((element.attachEvent) ? element.attachEvent('on' + myEvent, fnc) : element.addEventListener(myEvent, fnc, false));
}

var list = document.getElementById('list');
var items = list.getElementsByTagName('ul');
var items2 = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i = 0; len = items.length, i < len ; i++){
    items[i].parentNode.setAttribute('class','collapse');
}

addEvent(list, 'click', function(event) {
    for(var i = 0; len = items.length, i < len ; i++){
        event = event || window.event;

        event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble=true);

        if(event.target.getAttribute('class')==='collapse'){
            event.target.setAttribute('class','expand');
            target.setAttribute('class','expand');
        } else {
            event.target.setAttribute('class','collapse');
            target.setAttribute('class','collapse');
        }
    }
});
```

How do I bubble this properly so that I don't have to insert an event listener on every single list item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the handler with a check for the `nodeName` of the clicked element ( == `li`) and the existence of sub `<li>`-elements, so it acts only on those elements:

```
addEvent(list, 'click', function (e) {
     e = e || window.event;
     var from = e.target || e.srcElement;
     if (!/^li$/i.test(from.nodeName) ||
         !from.querySelectorAll('li').length) {return true;}
     var expand = /collapse/i.test(from.className || '');
     from.setAttribute('class', expand ? 'expand' : 'collapse');
});
```

Here's your rewritten [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/h6tcquxj/)

Comment: Your solution works great. I'm having a little trouble reading and understanding some of it(I'm not complaining). You passed the window object into the function so I'm wondering if you could have replaced `window.event` with `w.event`(would it work?) and also, I could use some decyphering/info on this shorthand: `!/^li$/i`. Also, you placed the addEvent function declaration at the end, rather than above it. I've been thought that declarations usually go above invocations. How does that work?

Comment: Hi @Puddingboy, the function in the jsFiddle is not part of the answer, it's just there to ensure that the global environment stays clean. But yes, in the jsfiddle it also could be `w.event`. Function *declarations* are always 'hoisted' to the top of the scope, so the place within the code is not relevant. Only if you assign a function to a variable, it should be assigned before you use it. `/^li$/i` is a regular expression, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp